# Index a list of lists

Tags: python, indexing, nested-lists

So sorry for bothering you with this probably stupid question, but I have been stuck (once again) on this for a while now.

I have list of lists

```
abc = [['date1','number1'],['date2','number2']...]
```

The dates might be the same. For example: date1 and date2 might both be '02/02/2015', while date3 could be '05/02/2015'.

When following the example, I would like to get the index of the element where the date matches the first time with a date I provide the function with. For example, something like

```
function(abc,'02/02/2015')
output: [0][0] (and only this, so not [1][0] as well)
```

OR

```
function(abc,'05/02/2015')
output: [2][0]
```

Does anybody know how to do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def firstMatch (date, lst):
    for i, sublist in enumerate(lst):
        if sublist[0] == date:
            return i
```

Essentially, you want to iterate through the list and check for each sublist if the first element matches your desired date. If that’s the case, just return the index you are currently at; otherwise continue to iterate.

```
>>> abc = [['02/02/2015', '1'], ['02/02/2015', '2'], ['05/02/2015', '3']]    
>>> firstMatch('02/02/2015', abc)
0
>>> firstMatch('05/02/2015', abc)
2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve that using a function like the following:

```
def match_date(l, d):
    return list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == d, l))[0]
```

which, thanks to the `filter()` builtin, will match the function given as first argument on each element of the list, and return a list with all values for which the function returned `True`. Thus, it will return the list of all dates matched within the list:

```
>>> def match_date(l, d):
...     return list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == d, l))[0]
... 
>>> abc = [['date1','number1'],['date2','number2']]
>>> match_date(abc, 'date2')
['date2', 'number2']
>>> abc = [['date1','number1'],['date2','number2'],['date2', 'number3'],['date3', 'number4']]
>>> match_date(abc, 'date2')
['date2', 'number2'], ['date2', 'number3']
```

from there, you can do:

```
>>> abc.index(match_date(abc, 'date2')[0])
1
```

which will give you the index of the first tuple being matched. I do not believe you need to have the second index, as you *know* that it's always `[0]`, as it's your data model.

To make it one function:

```
>>> def get_index_of_match_date(l, d):
...     return l.index(filter(lambda x: x[0] == d, l)[0])
... 
>>> get_index_of_match_date(abc, 'date2')
0
>>> get_index_of_match_date(abc, 'date2')
1
>>> get_index_of_match_date(abc, 'date3')
3
```

Comment: Note that in Python 3, `filter` returns a generator, so this won’t work without casting it to a list. Also, this solution requires you to iterate through the list multiple times.

Comment: indeed for the `filter` comment. But not entirely true for the second comment, as it's going to parse the list entirely once for `filter()`, but index will stop when matched, which makes it a less than `O(n*2)` algorithm, so it's not *multiple*, even though it's not *once* or *less than* once. The overhead is totally acceptable, except if you're google and dealing with gigabytes of data.

Comment: This wasn’t criticism. Iterating a list multiple times usually isn’t a problem at all. I just wanted to point it out, especially since it can be avoided by just remembering the index in the first iteration (as there is no need to know what other elements also match).

Comment: I did not take it as criticism, or only as positive criticism! Which is why I'm justifying my choice in my previous comment ;-) I also believe that as we're in python, the OP's request to work on indexes, which can be avoided most of the times, could actually be a bad workaround (X-Y Problem) of working against a filtered list, that wouldn't shadow duplicates as shown with my second and third snippets.